# Defining customElements in iFrame throws "DOMException: Operation not supported". Why?

Tags: javascript, iframe, custom-element

I want to add Custom Element definition to my iFrame.

In the main browser window the definition works perfectly fine:

`customElements.define("custom-tag", customTag)`

Then after moving the definition to the iFrame, I get `DOMException: operation not supported`. The function is there but is not supported.

`iFrame.contentWindow.customElements.define("custom-tag", customTag);`

Is there a particular reason for this? Is defining custom tags blocked in iFrame by design and cannot be worked around or should I include something in my iFrame configuration to allow this "unsafe" behaviour?

Comment: Can't your iframe just load the component?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inject a custom element from the main HTML document into an `<iframe>` element, you can add it inside a `<script>` element.

For example, via the `srcdoc` property:

```js
frame.srcdoc = `
  <script>
    class customTag extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
         super()
            this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
                .innerHTML = "Hello World"
        }
    } 
    customElements.define( 'custom-tag', customTag )
  <\/script>
  <custom-tag></custom-tag>
`
```

```html
<iframe id=frame></iframe>
```

Note the escape character `\` into the ending `</script>` tag.